# How to convert an xls file to mysql format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xls

I have tried the code below:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTablenNmeHere
FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I'm getting error:

> [Err] 1327 - Undeclared variable: NewTablenNmeHere

Comment: And what didn't work? Guess no one will be able to help you with a sophisticated error description like that.

Comment: [Err] 1327 - Undeclared variable: NewTablenNmeHere

Comment: @ilhan, you were voted down because you did not provide an error. Saying "didn't work" will get you downvotes 99% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OPENROWSET` seems to be a MS SQL command. I don't think it has an equivalent in mySQL.

The easiest method that comes to mind is

- Save the XLS file as CSV
- Use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to import the file into mySQL.

You can also use a graphical mySQL client like [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) to use a point-and-click dialog to determine which column goes where.